# Fetching information from a WebGrid in client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I am using a WebGrid to populate some information like this

```
<div id="interiorGrid">

    @{
        var interiorList = Model.Lists;
        var interiorGrid = new WebGrid(interiorList,
                                        columnNames: new[] { "FeatureValue"},
                                        canSort: false); }

    @interiorGrid.GetHtml(
                            tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",          
                            columns: interiorGrid.Columns(
                                     interiorGrid.Column("IsActive", header: "",
                                                                    format: @<text>
                                        <img id="@item.ID" src=@if (item.IsActive == true){@("../../Images/Active.png");}
                                                               else{@("../../Images/InActive.png");}
                                                            onclick="return toggle('@item.ID'); return false;" /></text>),
                                    interiorGrid.Column("FeatureValue", header: "", 
                                                         format: @<text><span id='featureValue'>@item.FeatureValue</span></text>)))

</div>
```

This is populating the data fine, and HTML code coming in page is like :

```
<div id="interiorGrid">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                                                                <img id="312864" src=../../Images/InActive.png                                                                     onclick="return toggle('312864'); return false;" /></td>
            <td><span id='featureValue'>Daytime Running Lamps</span></td>
        </tr>
        ------------MULTIPLE---------------------------
        <tr>
            <td>
                                                                <img id="312870" src=../../Images/Active.png                                                                     onclick="return toggle('312870'); return false;" /></td>
            <td><span id='featureValue'>Wipers, front intermittent</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

=============
I am trying to loop through this, and get each span text. I am trying code like this, but is not working :

```
var gridData = $('#interiorGrid table tr').each(function () {
            alert($(this).find('featureValue').text());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need the # to identifie the Id

```
alert($(this).find('#featureValue').text());
```

Comment: My bad..I missed it..Can you tell me, how to get that image src of the other td..which is having a dynamic ID

Comment: Take a look at the following links http://api.jquery.com/parent/ http://api.jquery.com/child/ You can select higher level tags, and then you can do your find. Don't forget to vote the answer so we can close this question